# Как отслеживать перемещение мыши над определенным виджетом? (Qt, C++)

Tags: c++, qt

Приветствую.

Я разрабатываю перетаскиваемые вкладки, как в хроме или Visual Studio (с возможностью становиться окном и обратно вкладкой, логика полностью одинаковая). Реализовал функцию преобразования вкладки в окно(при событии `mouseMoveEvent` ей присваивается `setParent(nullptr);`), также окно можно перемещать, если потянуть за вкладку.

Собственно **вопрос**:

Допустим, мы перетянули вкладку, и она стала отдельным окном. Как теперь при перетаскивании этого окна определить, что мы находимся над панелью вкладок другого окна (в этот момент окно должно обратно превратиться во вкладку)? Всё осложняется еще и тем, что панель вкладок может быть не одна, а несколько: мы можем создать неограниченное количество окон и внутри этих окон создать неограниченное количество вкладок, и к какой бы панели вкладок мы не поднесли наше окно, оно должно превратиться во вкладку именно внутри той панели вкладок, на которую мы навели.

Отсюда возникает мысль, что удобнее отслеживать перемещения вкладок(окон) на стороне панели вкладок, а не рассчитывать координаты всех доступных панелей вкладок. Т.е. панель вкладок как-то должна узнать, что над ней находится курсор мыши, нажата левая клавиша мыши и курсор тащит за собой вкладку, и после как-то добавить это окно к себе во вкладки.

Как это можно осуществить?

Comment: В Qt есть Drag and Drop http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/dnd.html

Comment: @Wanket нет, Drag and Drop - это не то. То, что мы можем наблюдать в хроме или студии - это не DnD, а именно перетаскивание настоящих окон.